# How to disable EF message: Context 'Context' started tracking 'Model' entity. Consider using

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm looking at my application log stream in Azure for an asp.net core 2 EF core web api and am getting bombarded by the message.

```
Context 'Context' started tracking 'Model' entity. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see key values.
```

Is there any way to disable/suppress these messages without turning tracking off in my code?

Edit:
Code from dbContextClass

```cs
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context (DbContextOptions<Context> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Model> Model { get; set; }
    
    /*protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // add your own configuration here
    }*/
}
```

Comment: What is the code of the `Context` class?

Comment: @GertArnold post updated.

Comment: Can you show your logging configuration? Basically you need to turn off logging for  `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking` category.

Answer (score 1):

When you query the database for some record without using `AsNoTracking`, EF Core will start tracking it in current context. `AsNoTracking` is one solution as you don't want EF Core to track any modifications to that. In many cases not having `AsNoTracking` is fine as long as you don't add/attach/update entity with same id in the context. But it is good to have it explicitly when tracking is not required.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking).

Also, the [`LogStartedTracking`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.internal.corestrings.logstartedtracking?view=efcore-2.1) field only support Entity Framework Core 2.1, you could try to upgrade your EF Core version.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't the AsNoTracking only for read only queries? If I'm doing actual database updated wouldn't the changes not be saved?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have logTo() if EF core configuration in your startup.cs or program.cs. Add second parameter that limits logging level.

```
.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Warning)
```